# assign random id's to names in address book

Tags: python-3.x, list

So im trying to assing random ids from randint to names in a list, i need the ids to be displayed next to the names too, so far what i use to read the names is this

```
if os.path.isfile("contactos.txt"):
with open("contactos.txt") as f:
    csv_list = f.readlines()
    for contact_line in csv_list:
        contact_data = contact_line.rstrip().split(",")
        contact = Person(contact_data[0],
                         contact_data[1], 
                         contact_data[2],
                         contact_data[3])
        contacts.append(contact)
```

and i write the names with this:

```
with open("contactos.txt", "w") as f:
for contact in contacts:
    f.write(f"{contact.primero},{contact.segundo},{contact.edad},{contact.numero_telefono}\n")
```

my contacts are stored in

```
contacts = list()
```

but i cant figure out how to assing them id's.  any help please? i also need to be able to delete contacts from the list but im clueless

Comment: Do you want IDs to be integers, or just some unique id? Are there any other data points that alone or in combination are unique to each row? It would probably help to see the `Person` implementation as it is likely you will set the id in it.

Comment: hey Jon, you can check my github under random repo, there's the code and the stuff i need.  https://github.com/Nipicoco/random